# How can I set this up? $\iiint dz\,dy\,dx$

Tags: integration, area, volume

Write an iterated triple integral in the order $dz\,dy\,dx$ for the volume of the region bounded below by the $xy$-plane and above by the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ and lying inside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$?

---

From the question, I know that $z=0$, but how can I write it as a triple integral $dz\,dy\,dx$?

$$\iiint dz\,dy\,dx$$

Comment: The outermost differentials are $dy$ and $dx$. Try to start by showing the region lies above a specific domain in the $xy$ plane. What is that domain?

Comment: I don't know the problem doesn't tell you that

Comment: @jonwick the domain of integration is the region whose volume you're calculating

Comment: I know , but whats the domain?

Comment: The problem *does* tell you that. Can you sketch the region?

Comment: @UmbertoP. no, can you do it for me?